# Change value of parameter using button

Tags: javascript

Cannot change value of parameter using button.

```
    <script>
    var jArray= [{"value":"1"},{"value":"3"}];

    var array= [];

    var Id= 31;

    for (var i = 0; i < jArray.length; i++) {
        var id = {
            value: parseInt(jArray[i].value)
        };
        array.push(id);
    }





    function getBack() {
        if (Id== array[0]){
            console.log(Id);
        }
        else {
            for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                if (Id== array[i]){
                    Id= array[i - 1];
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<button onclick="getPreviousMap()">get previous map</button>
```

When I click on it, nothing happens. If I check my console, it stays on the same value.

Comment: To make this easier, can you show the rendered javscript (with the PHP tags removed and actual data in there).

Comment: Yes, I edited my original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing to access the `time_id` when comparing `currentTimeId` with `jAllTimeIdsInt[i]`. Also, `time_id` is missing when you assign `currentTimeId` inside of the if statements.

For example in the `getNextMap` method.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < jAllTimeIdsInt.length; i++) {
    if (currentTimeId == jAllTimeIdsInt[i].time_id) { // <-- access time_id
        currentTimeId = jAllTimeIdsInt[i + 1].time_id; // <-- assign time_id
        console.log(currentTimeId);
    }
}
```

`getPreviousMap` needs to be modified accordingly.

Also, when you execute your code with the `time_id` adjustment, you will need a break statement inside of the for loop when the correct `currentTimeId` is found, otherwise you will get a TypeError.